# I would like to the take a table and arrange the data in a way to allow me to create a stacked bar chart

Tags: r

I would like to Re- Arrange the below table:

```
    Quarter        Current         Delinquent     Default 

1 Q1 2020       6445687          1521323       1607303
```

Into This:

```
Quarter  Amount   Class
Q1 2020  6445687  Current
Q1 2020  1521323  Delinquent
Q1 2020  1607303  Default
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do,

```
df %>% pivot_longer(-c(Quarter), values_to = "Value", names_to = "Class")# A 

tibble: 3 x 3
  Quarter Class        Value
  <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>
1 Q1 2020 Current    6445687
2 Q1 2020 Delinquent 1521323
3 Q1 2020 Default    1607303
```

**Data**

```
df = data.frame(Quarter = 'Q1 2020', Current = 6445687, Delinquent = 1521323, Default = 1607303)
```